# snowflake SQL UDF not supporting subquery

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Snowflake SQL UDF working fine when hard coded values are passed as input parameter but fails when the UDF is used in SELECT clause by passing the actual columns as input parameter.

Have checked on this error with snowflake community but seems like this error was reported 4 years ago and there was no solution yet.

[Snowflake Community thread](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008NspxcSAB/sql-compilation-error-unsupported-subquery-type-cannot-be-evaluated?t=1665614676835&searchQuery)

Can someone help with alternate solution to overcome this bug with snowflake please.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(BASE_NET_VALUE FLOAT,EX_PRICE_DATE DATE,EX_RATE_TYPE VARCHAR(20),FROM_CURR VARCHAR(10),TO_CURR VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
COMMENT='This function will return Ex rate value, net value and converted net value based on the input parameter.'
AS $$
 
case 
    when FROM_CURR = TO_CURR then ('|'||BASE_NET_VALUE||'|'||BASE_NET_VALUE)
    
else 
    (select (EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE||'|'||ACT_BASE_NET_VALUE||'|'||CONV_NET_VALUE) 
    from
        (select
            case 
                when ( (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES) < 0 ) then round((BASE_NET_VALUE / power(10, -1 * (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES)))/TCURF.FROM_CURRENCY_RATIO,2) 
                when ( (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES) > 0 ) then round((BASE_NET_VALUE * power(10, 1 * (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES)))/TCURF.FROM_CURRENCY_RATIO,2)
            else round(BASE_NET_VALUE,2) end as ACT_BASE_NET_VALUE
            ,round((ACT_BASE_NET_VALUE * EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE),2) as CONV_NET_VALUE
            ,EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE as EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE
            
        from MY_SCHEMA.MY_EXCHANGE_RATES EXRATE
        LEFT JOIN MY_SCHEMA.CURRENCY CURRENCY ON CURRENCY.CURRENCY_KEY = FROM_CURR AND CURRENCY.DELETED = 'N'
        LEFT JOIN (select * from MY_SCHEMA.EXCHANGE_RATE_CONVERSION_FACTORS where DELETED = 'N'
                    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE,FROM_CURRENCY,TO_CURRENCY,VALID_FROM ORDER BY VALID_FROM DESC) = 1) TCURF
                    ON TCURF.FROM_CURRENCY = FROM_CURR AND TCURF.TO_CURRENCY = TO_CURR AND TCURF.EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE = EX_RATE_TYPE
                    
        where equal_null(FROM_CURR,EXRATE.SOURCE_CURRENCY) 
            and EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE = EX_RATE_TYPE
            and (EX_PRICE_DATE BETWEEN EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_DATE AND EXRATE.VALID_TO_DATE)
            and EXRATE.TARGET_CURRENCY = TO_CURR
            and EXRATE.DELETED = 'N'
        ))
end
$$;
```

Above function works when I call the UDF with sample values passed as input parameter.

```
select 
     try_to_double(split_part(my_schema.UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(44131.26,to_date('2020-04-24'),'M','EUR','USD'),'|',1)) as EX_RATE_VALUE 
    ,try_to_double(split_part(my_schema.UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(44131.26,to_date('2020-04-24'),'M','EUR','USD'),'|',2)) as BASE_VALUE
    ,try_to_double(split_part(my_schema.UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(44131.26,to_date('2020-04-24'),'M','EUR','USD'),'|',3)) as USD_BASE_VALUE
 
;
```

But the same is giving "SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" error when tried with select clause by passing the actual columns as input parameter.

```
select
    TXN_NO
    ,try_to_double(split_part(my_schema.UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(NET_VALUE,PRICE_DATE,RATE_TYPE,SOURCE_CURRENCY,TARGET_CURRENCY),'|',1)) as EX_RATE_VALUE 
    ,try_to_double(split_part(my_schema.UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(NET_VALUE,PRICE_DATE,RATE_TYPE,SOURCE_CURRENCY,TARGET_CURRENCY),'|',2)) as BASE_VALUE
    ,try_to_double(split_part(my_schema.UDF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(NET_VALUE,PRICE_DATE,RATE_TYPE,SOURCE_CURRENCY,TARGET_CURRENCY),'|',3)) as USD_BASE_VALUE
 
FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TRANSACTION_TABLE
WHERE TXN_NO = 'ABCXYZ'
;
```

Comment: Have you tried leveraging a CTE instead of sub-queries?  That can often get Snowflake to interpret the query a little differently and avoid that error.

Comment: you UDF feels like it missing some form of aggregation/row-limiting.. some of those joins like the `EX_PRICE_DATE BETWEEN exrate.exchange_rate_date AND exrate.valid_to_date` feels like it will get many rows. Also your ROW_NUMBER has `valid_from` in both the partition by and order by.

Comment: @MikeWalton, Seems like SQL UDF is not supporting CTE. Is there anyway I can use this joins within a function and call function on the fly in SELECT clause by just passing the columns as input parameter.

SimeonPilgrim, Yes, I can remove valid_from in Partition and use only in ORDER BY clause and price date filtered using between is working with use case scenario. Is there any possibilities of creating function with these joins and use it on the fly in SELECT Clause.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, In my use case scenario `EX_PRICE_DATE BETWEEN exrate.exchange_rate_date AND exrate.valid_to_date` is going to return only one matching entries. As the given transaction date is going to lie in between exchange rate date and valid to date. So its not returning multiple rows. Still i'm looking for any help on this. I was trying with Python UDF in snowflake as well but couldn't execute query within python UDF. tried multiple ways still couldn't any solution for this. As said above CTE concept is not accepted within SQL UDF it seems in snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

So to work this into a cleaner example, I started by refactoring your code, and at one point it gets down to some corrolated values (BASE_NET_VALUE) is needed.

So I made a new function that just does the math bits:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_math_bits_curr_conv_values(base_net_value FLOAT, exchange_rate_value FLOAT, currency_decimal_places INT, from_currency_ratio FLOAT, from_curr VARCHAR(10), to_curr VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
 
CASE 
    WHEN from_curr = to_curr THEN ( '|' || base_net_value || '|' || base_net_value ) 
ELSE 
    (SELECT ( exchange_rate_value || '|' || act_base_net_value || '|' || conv_net_value ) 
    FROM
        (SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN ( (2 - currency_decimal_places) < 0 ) THEN round( (base_net_value / power(10, -1 * (2 - currency_decimal_places)) ) / from_currency_ratio, 2) 
                WHEN ( (2 - currency_decimal_places) > 0 ) THEN round( (base_net_value * power(10,  1 * (2 - currency_decimal_places)) ) / from_currency_ratio, 2)
                ELSE round(base_net_value, 2) 
            END AS act_base_net_value
            ,round((act_base_net_value * exchange_rate_value), 2) AS conv_net_value
        )
    )
END
$$;
```

and this can be used to build the answer parts you want mostly like how the old UDF worked, and mixed with some example data:

```
with MY_TRANSACTION_TABLE(NET_VALUE, SOURCE_CURRENCY, TARGET_CURRENCY) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'USD', 'NZD'),
    (100, 'SAME', 'SAME')
)
select
    udf_math_bits_curr_conv_values(mtt.NET_VALUE,  1.023::float, 3, 1.023::float, mtt.SOURCE_CURRENCY, mtt.TARGET_CURRENCY) as r1
    ,split(r1, '|') as AA
    ,try_to_double(AA[0]::text) as EX_RATE_VALUE 
    ,try_to_double(AA[1]::text) as BASE_VALUE
    ,try_to_double(AA[2]::text) as USD_BASE_VALUE
FROM MY_TRANSACTION_TABLE as mtt
```

gives:

| R1 | AA | EX_RATE_VALUE | BASE_VALUE | USD_BASE_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.023|0.1|0.1 | [ "1.023", "0.1", "0.1" ] | 1.023 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| |100|100 | [ "", "100", "100" ] | null | 100 | 100 |

this is just show the same currency CASE still works.

then we move the rest of the UDF into a join able table..

like this:

```
SELECT
    exrate.source_currency AS from_curr /* equal_null(from_curr , exrate.source_currency)  */
    ,exrate.target_currency AS to_curr
    ,exrate.exchange_rate_date
    ,exrate.valid_to_date
    ,exrate.exchange_rate_type as ex_rate_type
    ,currency.currency_decimal_places
    ,tcurf.from_currency_ratio
    ,exrate.exchange_rate_value
FROM my_schema.my_exchange_rates AS exrate
LEFT JOIN my_schema.currency AS currency 
    ON currency.currency_key = exrate.source_currency 
        AND currency.deleted = 'N'
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        from_currency, 
        to_currency, 
        exchange_rate_type, 
        from_currency_ratio
    FROM my_schema.exchange_rate_conversion_factors 
    WHERE deleted = 'N'
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY exchange_rate_type, from_currency, to_currency, valid_from ORDER BY valid_from DESC) = 1
) AS tcurf
    ON tcurf.from_currency = exrate.source_currency 
        AND tcurf.to_currency = exrate.target_currency 
        AND tcurf.exchange_rate_type = exrate.exchange_rate_type        
WHERE exrate.deleted = 'N'
```

which we join to the main SQL like:

```
select
    udf_math_bits_curr_conv_values(mtt.NET_VALUE, x.exchange_rate_value, x.from_currency_ratio, x.from_currency_ratio, mtt.source_currency, mtt.target_currency) as r1
    ,split(r1, '|') as AA
    ,try_to_double(AA[0]::text) as EX_RATE_VALUE 
    ,try_to_double(AA[1]::text) as BASE_VALUE
    ,try_to_double(AA[2]::text) as USD_BASE_VALUE
FROM MY_TRANSACTION_TABLE as mtt
JOIN (
    SELECT
        exrate.source_currency AS from_curr
        ,exrate.target_currency AS to_curr
        ,exrate.exchange_rate_date
        ,exrate.valid_to_date
        ,exrate.exchange_rate_type as ex_rate_type
        ,currency.currency_decimal_places
        ,tcurf.from_currency_ratio
        ,exrate.exchange_rate_value
    FROM my_schema.my_exchange_rates AS exrate
    LEFT JOIN my_schema.currency AS currency 
        ON currency.currency_key = exrate.source_currency 
            AND currency.deleted = 'N'
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            from_currency, 
            to_currency, 
            exchange_rate_type, 
            from_currency_ratio
        FROM my_schema.exchange_rate_conversion_factors 
        WHERE deleted = 'N'
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY exchange_rate_type, from_currency, to_currency, valid_from ORDER BY valid_from DESC) = 1
    ) AS tcurf
        ON tcurf.from_currency = exrate.source_currency 
            AND tcurf.to_currency = exrate.target_currency 
            AND tcurf.exchange_rate_type = exrate.exchange_rate_type        
    WHERE exrate.deleted = 'N'
) AS x
    ON mtt.price_date BETWEEN x.exchange_rate_date AND x.valid_to_date
        AND mtt.rate_type = x.ex_rate_type
        AND equal_null(mtt.source_currency, X.from_curr)
        AND mtt.target_currency = x.to_curr
WHERE mtt.txn_no = 'ABCXYZ'
```

I have not ran this final SQL, because I don't have the tables.. but it should work/ point you in the correct direction.

If you want to avoid the large sub-select, that part could be pushed into a CTE or UDTF

Comment: Thanks. However I want these logic's to be executed within a function and wanted to use this with other objects. Seems like SQL UDF will not support WITH clause getting error when tried to have WITH clause in UDF. I was just trying to use this function and get the currency conversion values and converted amount by passing the respective input parameter on the fly in select statement while retrieving data from any of objects which requires a Amount to be converted to different currency.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have tried to achieve this using UDTF but not sure if this is best practice to have. Please reply if this is not an ideal way to do.

UDTF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDTF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(BASE_NET_VALUE FLOAT,EX_PRICE_DATE DATE,EX_RATE_TYPE VARCHAR(20),FROM_CURR VARCHAR(10),TO_CURR VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE (CONVERTED_NET_PRICE VARCHAR(16777216))
LANGUAGE SQL
COMMENT='This function will return Ex rate value, net value and converted net value based on the input parameter.'
AS $$
select
    case 
        when FROM_CURR = TO_CURR then ('1'||'|'||BASE_NET_VALUE)
        
    else 
        (EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE||'|'||round(((case 
                                                when ( (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES) < 0 ) then round((BASE_NET_VALUE / power(10, -1 * (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES)))/TCURF.FROM_CURRENCY_RATIO,2)
                                                when ( (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES) > 0 ) then round((BASE_NET_VALUE * power(10, 1 * (2 - CURRENCY.CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES)))/TCURF.FROM_CURRENCY_RATIO,2)
                                            else round(BASE_NET_VALUE,2) end) * EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_VALUE),2))
    end as CONVERTED_NET_PRICE
                
from MY_SCHEMA.MY_EXCHANGE_RATES EXRATE
LEFT JOIN MY_SCHEMA.CURRENCY CURRENCY ON CURRENCY.CURRENCY_KEY = FROM_CURR AND CURRENCY.DELETED = 'N'
LEFT JOIN (select * from MY_SCHEMA.EXCHANGE_RATE_CONVERSION_FACTORS where DELETED = 'N'
            QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE,FROM_CURRENCY,TO_CURRENCY ORDER BY VALID_FROM DESC) = 1) TCURF
            ON TCURF.FROM_CURRENCY = FROM_CURR AND TCURF.TO_CURRENCY = TO_CURR AND TCURF.EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE = EX_RATE_TYPE
            
where equal_null(FROM_CURR,EXRATE.SOURCE_CURRENCY) 
    and EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_TYPE = EX_RATE_TYPE
    and (EX_PRICE_DATE BETWEEN EXRATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_DATE AND EXRATE.VALID_TO_DATE)
    and EXRATE.TARGET_CURRENCY = TO_CURR
    and EXRATE.DELETED = 'N'

$$;
```

Sample query which worked fine

```
SELECT
    TXN.TXN_NO,TXN.NET_VALUE,TXN.PRICE_DATE,TXN.RATE_TYPE,TXN.SOURCE_CURRENCY,TXN.TARGET_CURRENCY
    ,split_part(T.CONVERTED_NET_PRICE,'|',1) as EX_RATE_VALUE
    ,split_part(T.CONVERTED_NET_PRICE,'|',2) as USD_NET_VALUE
    
FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TRANSACTION_TABLE TXN
,TABLE(MY_SCHMEA.UDTF_GET_CURR_CONV_VALUES(TXN.NET_VALUE,TXN.PRICE_DATE,TXN.RATE_TYPE,TXN.SOURCE_CURRENCY,TXN.TARGET_CURRENCY)) T
WHERE TXN.TXN_NO = 'ABCXYZ'
```